# Vmware 6 - snapshot on one host fails

Tags: vmware-esxi

Running ***Vmware Sphere 6 + Vcenter server standard***.
Have two virtual machines running.

- **vcenter virtual machine**
- **ubuntu virtual machine**

I can take a snapshot of vcenter virtual machine, bu can no longer take any snapshots on the ubuntu virtual machine. I hard reboot of the Esxi host seems to resolve but after creating the first snapshot I can no longer perform the operation.

**/var/log/hostd.log**

```
2015-12-22T13:41:58.224Z info hostd[21480B70] [Originator@6876 sub=Hostsvc.DvsTracker opID=8e5fb06e user=vpxuser] FetchUplinkDVPortgroups: added 0 items                                                                                                                
[LikewiseGetDomainJoinInfo:355] QueryInformation(): ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2/0):                                                                                                                                                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:05.241Z info hostd[21480B70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/56782761-925450e3-fc3f-0cc47a7b41f2/Pirate1/Pirate1.vmx] State Transition (VM_STATE_ON -> VM_STATE_CREATE_SCREENSHOT)                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:05.270Z info hostd[2208CB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/56782761-925450e3-fc3f-0cc47a7b41f2/Pirate1/Pirate1.vmx] State Transition (VM_STATE_CREATE_SCREENSHOT -> VM_STATE_ON)                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:05.270Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Guestsvc.GuestFileTransferImpl] Entered VmPowerStateListener                                                                                                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:05.270Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Guestsvc.GuestFileTransferImpl] VmPowerStateListener succeeded                                                                                                                                       
2015-12-22T13:42:05.270Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Hbrsvc] Replicator: powerstate change VM: 4 Old: 1 New: 1                                                                                                                                            
2015-12-22T13:42:11.897Z info hostd[21480B70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc.TaskManager opID=0f9ccf45-2bc3-41a1-bd45-895b0e08081d-452-ngc-3-5-b079 user=vpxuser:BOMMACHINE.LOCAL\Administrator] Task Created : haTask-4-vim.VirtualMachine.createSnapshot-1524            
2015-12-22T13:42:11.897Z warning hostd[220CDB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/56782761-925450e3-fc3f-0cc47a7b41f2/Pirate1/Pirate1.vmx opID=0f9ccf45-2bc3-41a1-bd45-895b0e08081d-452-ngc-3-5-b079 user=vpxuser:BOMMACHINE.LOCAL\Administrator] State Trans
2015-12-22T13:42:11.897Z info hostd[220CDB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Default opID=0f9ccf45-2bc3-41a1-bd45-895b0e08081d-452-ngc-3-5-b079 user=vpxuser:BOMMACHINE.LOCAL\Administrator] AdapterServer caught exception: vim.fault.InvalidState                               
2015-12-22T13:42:11.897Z info hostd[220CDB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc.TaskManager opID=0f9ccf45-2bc3-41a1-bd45-895b0e08081d-452-ngc-3-5-b079 user=vpxuser:BOMMACHINE.LOCAL\Administrator] Task Completed : haTask-4-vim.VirtualMachine.createSnapshot-1524 Status er
2015-12-22T13:42:13.482Z info hostd[2208CB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/56782761-925450e3-fc3f-0cc47a7b41f2/Pirate1/Pirate1.vmx] State Transition (VM_STATE_ON -> VM_STATE_CREATE_SCREENSHOT)                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:13.511Z info hostd[2208CB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/56782761-925450e3-fc3f-0cc47a7b41f2/Pirate1/Pirate1.vmx] State Transition (VM_STATE_CREATE_SCREENSHOT -> VM_STATE_ON)                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:13.511Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Guestsvc.GuestFileTransferImpl] Entered VmPowerStateListener                                                                                                                                         
2015-12-22T13:42:13.511Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Guestsvc.GuestFileTransferImpl] VmPowerStateListener succeeded                                                                                                                                       
2015-12-22T13:42:13.511Z info hostd[FFB4CA80] [Originator@6876 sub=Hbrsvc] Replicator: powerstate change VM: 4 Old: 1 New: 1                                                                                                                                            
~
```

Comment: What options did you select when creating the snapshot ?

Comment: non I left both options unchecked - snapshot virtual machine memory & quiesce guest file system

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of VM Tools installation.  A failed VM Tools installation can cause this issue.

VM Tools installation status can be found in the virtual machine's log file located at:

```
/vmfs/volumes/virtual_machine_datastore/virtual_machine_folder/vmware.log
```

If VM Tools is not the issue you will find other useful troubleshooting information in the `vmware.log` file.

Comment: vmware tools is installed and working as far as I can tell.

Comment: Shows vmware tools is running on the machine.

Comment: Did you examine the VM's vmware.log file?